# Let $\{H,*\}$ be a subgroup of a group $\{G,*\}$. Prove that if $x\in yH$, then $xH=yH$.

Tags: group-theory

I really can't figure this out. I assumed I should start by using the double inclusion method:

Assume $x\in yH$.
Then $x=y*h$, $y\in G$, $h\in H$.
Then somehow show $x\in xH$.

Then show if $x\in xH$ that $y\in yH$.

But now I think that might not be the way to solve it.

Any advice?

Comment: Subgroups contain the identity, so of course $x$ is in $xH$.

Answer (score 1):

To show the double inclusion, you have to show that $xH \subseteq yH$, by taking an elemement $a\in xH$ and showing that $a \in yH$ and the reverse inclusion, $yH \subseteq xH$, by taking an element $b\in yH$ and showing that $b \in xH$.

So if you take $a\in xH$ then $a=x*h_1$ for some $h_1 \in H$. Now $x \in yH$ which means that $x= y*h_2$ for some $h_2 \in H$, then what can you say about $a$?

Can you imagine how does the other inclusion may go?

Answer (score 0):

First, you prove that $xH \subset yH$. Indeed, one has if $z\in xH$, there exists $h'\in H$ such that $$z = xh' = (yh)h' = y(hh') \in yH.$$

Second, you prove that $yh \in xH$. If $z \in yH$, then $z = yh_1$ for $h_1 \in H$, so $z = (xh^{-1})h_1 = x(h^{-1}h_1) \in xH.$